# ulimit to limit memory usage of a program

Tags: linux, memory-management, centos

I want to limit the memory usage of a program. I searched online and found that ulimit -v could be used to do that. After using that command, I could see the limitation using ulimit -a. However, my program still uses the same amount of memory. I checked the memory usage with top command while the program is running. I didn't see the limitation takes place. Is there anything wrong? I am using CentOS Linux release 7.1.1503 (Core).